# Wordpress styling for admin panel

Tags: css, wordpress, admin, preview, area

I have a wordpress site that I am working on.  The frontend of a section is working fine.  But that section is breaking in the admin panel preview area.

What I have searched till now has led me to the whole page of dashboard styling solutions.  What I require is to target the content in the preview area.

I also have solution but that is not working on server side.  It is working fine on local server.

```
function load_admin_style() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'admin_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/admin-style.css', false, '1.0.0' );
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'load_admin_style' );
```

Have not been able to find solution for this yet.  A little help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Has admin-style.css been uploaded to your server? 2) Does the admin-style.css appear in the HTML source code?

Comment: @user 1) yes. 2) No.

Comment: @userX

This code is sufficient to target the content in the preview area.

I had to delete the existing file from the server and re-load the same.

After few moments, it reflected the desired result.

I think it was more cache problem than anything else.

Also, have to target the element with proper inheritance.

Thanks for answers.

Cheers.

Comment: Glad you solved it, cheers mate